# Change ordering arguments for cross sells in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

Trying to order my cross sells on the cart page to the menu order defined on the product. Ordered the specific products 1 2 3 4 5 etc. but it displays 5 4 3 2 1. 
So I thought to try change the order to asc/desc to fix that but this is the code ive got so far. What would be the way to solve this?
Thanks!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cross_sells_orderby', 'custom_cross_sells_orderby', 10, 1 );
function custom_cross_sells_orderby( $orderby, $order ){
    $orderby = 'menu_order';
    $order = 'DESC';
    return $orderby;
    return $order;
}
```

Comment: woocommerce_cross_sells_orderby only accepts one parameter

Comment: remove $order = 'DESC' from your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is separated hooks for cross sells **order by** and **order**. The [default behavior for cross sells](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-woocommerce_cross_sell_display.html#1557)  **order**is already **"desc"**, so Try to use **"asc"** instead:

```
// Order by
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cross_sells_orderby', 'filter_cross_sells_orderby', 10, 1 );
function filter_cross_sells_orderby( $orderby ){
    return 'menu_order'; // Default is 'rand'
}

// Order
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cross_sells_order', 'filter_cross_sells_order', 10, 1 );
function filter_cross_sells_order( $order ){
    return 'asc'; // Default is 'desc'
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should better work.